# How can I declare a pointer structure using {}?

Tags: c, declaration, structure

This probably is one of the easiest question ever in C programming language...

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node * after;
  struct node * before;
}node;

struct node head = {10,&head,&head};
```

Is there a way I can make head to be *head [make it a pointer] and still have the availability to use '{ }' [{10,&head,&head}] to declare an instance of head and still leave it out in the global scope?

For example:

```
 //not legal!!!
 struct node *head = {10,&head,&head};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node * after;
  struct node * before;
}node;
int main() {

    struct node* head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //allocate memory
    *head = (struct node){10,head,head}; //cast to struct node

    printf("%d", head->data);

}
```

Something as simple as `struct node *head = {10, head, head}` is not going to work because you haven't allocated the memory for the struct (the int and two pointers).

**Solution 2:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node * after;
  struct node * before;
}node;
int main() {

    struct node* head = &(struct node){10,head,head};

    printf("%d", head->data);

}
```

This will go out of scope - Solution 1 is superior for this reason and since you're creating a linked list, I believe you *need* heap allocated memory - not stack allocated.

Comment: In other words I cannot allocate memory out in the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

You can make head a pointer, but you'll need to initialize it in a function.

```
struct node head_node;
struct node *head = &head_node;

void
initialize() {
    *head = {10,&head_node,&head_node};
}
```

There's no way you can initialize head ptr directly in global scope.